# Bootstrap Dropdown always get focused when pressing enter key in form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with different fields inside. And I am using a dropdown button instead of normal select tag for better user experience. However, the problem is that this dropdown always gets focused when I press enter key on other text input fields. This is annoying and causing trouble.

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="dropdown-label">
                Test
            </span>
          </button>
          <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-small btn-white dropdown-toggle">
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select" role="menu">
              <li><a>
                Testing 1
              </a></li>
              <li><a>
                Testing 2
              </a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ergLb/

Do you guys have any idea why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like somehow by default when the `enter` key was pressed inside the textbox, it'll trigger the click event on your dropdown. You can use `e.preventDefault()` or `return false` in order to prevent this default behavior:

```
$(".form-control").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ergLb/1/)**

Comment: Someone probably entered some piece of code that triggers a form submit when enter is pressed; but implemented it using the submit button's `click` event rather than the form's `submit` event. That would explain why OP's button is getting clicked. @OP: for fun, could you check if the same problem exists if you use a `<select>` instead? If it doesn't, I think my interpretation is correct. That would also mean your answer is not 100% guaranteed to solve it, since that wrong implementation might get triggered before yours. I think...

Comment: I know that this answer might be incorrect in other cases, but anyway, it works for me :)

Answer (score 15):

I have added type="button" and it works.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3886

Answer (score 5):

mdo gave the answer in a bootstrap issue ticket: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3886
You forgot `type=button` at the button, which triggers the dropdown toggle. The code should read like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-small btn-white dropdown-toggle">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
```